# OpenVPN service won't start on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, openvpn

I'm not totally new to openvpn but I am new to 20.04

A fresh install helpfully has openvpn installed by default. The difference between it and 16.04 is that the /etc/openvpn directory has 2 sub directories client and server.

I've tried my client .conf file in both /etc/openvpn and /etc/openvpn/client and it won't start.

I've run openvpn manually specifying the config file and it connects perfectly.

Starting the service does nothing so the problem is how openvpn integrates with ubuntu 20.04

Where does the openvpn install for ubuntu 20.04 expect the config files to be placed?
Where are the logs for the service or how do I get logs of where it's looking?

Is there any other thing i  shold be looking at? Sadly any attempt to google config file location gets you either /etc/openvpn or the location of the example files :-/

```
root@somewhere:/etc/openvpn# /etc/init.d/openvpn status
● openvpn.service - OpenVPN service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2021-04-13 11:17:53 UTC; 22h ago
   Main PID: 996 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 16624)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/openvpn.service

Apr 13 11:17:53 somewhere systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service...
Apr 13 11:17:53 somewhere systemd[1]: Finished OpenVPN service.

root@somewhere:/etc/openvpn# tail -50 /var/log/syslog
...
Apr 14 09:22:05 somewhere systemd-timesyncd[898]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.94.4:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Apr 14 09:30:59 somewhere systemd[1]: openvpn.service: Succeeded.
Apr 14 09:30:59 somewhere systemd[1]: Stopped OpenVPN service.
Apr 14 09:31:06 somewhere systemd[1]: Starting OpenVPN service...
Apr 14 09:31:06 somewhere systemd[1]: Finished OpenVPN service.
root@somewhere :/home/somewhere # ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:c0:4d:a6:ee:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp6s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:8d:46:85:90:3f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
root@somewhere :/home/somewhere #
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it i think...

I had a rogue ifup script in /etc/networkd-dispatcher/routable.d/50-ifup-hooks that was adding a drop route.

I also uninstalled and reinstalled openvpn.